# Why aren't all smaller components of 64-bit registers accessible and readily usable?

Tags: cpu

A register in a CPU can be much more well utilized if it could be divided and its parts can be used independently. For example, if you need 8 8-bit values, you could just use a single 64-bit register, and each 8-bit segment could be treated independently of one another. But the way CPUs are designed, using 8 64-bit registers with only the first 8 bits of each used is the norm. And extracting the higher order bytes typically requires a shift and a bitmask. Why are they designed like that?

Comment: Related: [Why is handling word sizes smaller than the native size of a processor sometimes slower?](/q/162433)

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two main reasons explaining the current design:

1. it is a historical choice that took into account the manufacturing process (hardware complexity and realization cost) which had to be reduced,
2. the architecture currently used allows you to do what you are asking for at a reasonable price, paid in terms of additional clock cycles (through shifts and bit-masking).

It is in theory possible to design a CPU having some flag that switches the register's operation mode from the classic one to the one you suggested, however, this choice would require additional circuitry for managing concurrency-related issues, namely, locking, caching, and synchronization of the CPU pipeline.

Let's suppose the converse, that is, the CPU was always in this mode. In that case, you were just asking for many more tiny 8-bit long registers. In this situation, I wonder: how could I employ 64 (or 32) bits to represent big numbers? I think I would be forced to implement all relevant integer operations (with carries, borrows, and the rest). Nowadays, we want those operations to be out of the box.

Lastly, observe that there exist microprocessors behaving vaguely the way you describe: [Intel CPUs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture) historically split registers in sub-registers that can be manipulated directly but with some limitations.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is *rename registers*.

An out-of-order processor that is told “add register r2 to r1” will not actually modify r1 but find a new register rx, set rx = r1+r2, and from then on uses rx instead of r1. This is done because there might be other unfinished instructions that still need to use the original value of r1.

Now if you say “add r2 and r3 and store in the lower 8 bits of r1” that instruction would need three operands -r1,r2 and r3- to store the result into rx.

Intel processors have these instructions and they are slower than larger instructions and avoided.